# aspx page don't call ajax method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I'm building an aspx page. In this page, there is this js function:

```
window.feed = function(callback) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "Default.aspx/OnSubmit",
          data: dataValue,
          error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              alert("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString() + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
          },
          complete: function (jqXHR, status) {
              //alert("complete: " + status + "\n\nResponse: " + jqXHR.responseText);
              var tick = {};
              tick.plot0 = parseInt(10 + 90 * Math.random(), 10);
              tick.plot1 = parseInt(10 + 90 * Math.random(), 10);
              callback(JSON.stringify(tick));
          }
      });
    };
```

This function should call this method of backend:

```
[WebMethod]
        public static string OnSubmit(string name, bool isGoing, string returnAddress)
        {
            return "it worked";
        }
```

but if I try to start my page, this method is never called.

If I delete ajax function and write for example "alert(pippo)"; this alert is display every 500 millisecond.

Where is the error?

Comment: try `"Default/OnSubmit"` as the url

Comment: have you looked in your browser's console and/or network tools to see what is going on?

Comment: Ok, now works, with Default/OnSubmit